# Upload Test Results on a site

Tags: c#, powershell, testing, automation, azure-pipelines

I am trying to upload my test results created via pipeline on to a website. I want to do it using Azure pipeline only, is there any task I can add to my pipeline which will take the files created during test run and upload it on to the site, which we have created for uploading test results so that anyone can visit and check the site.

I tried to look into some Pipeline tasks but was not able to find any such.

Comment: Do you want the actual results or just some kind of "Test-Status-Tag" like you can see in some GitHub Readmes, for example?